# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n +y_n) = L + M$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

I am just wondering if I can take $ {\varepsilon}' =  \varepsilon _a + \varepsilon _b $ where $|x_n - L| < \varepsilon _a $ and $|y_n - M| < \varepsilon_b$

If not could someone point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to deal with this is to say:

> Given $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $N_1 > 0$ such that
>
> $$n > N_1 \ \Longrightarrow  \ |x_n - L| < \epsilon/2$$
>
> and an $N_2 > 0$ such that
>
> $$n > N_2 \ \Longrightarrow \ |y_n - M| < \epsilon/2$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: I can see what you are doing. We will get the sum of the $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$'s equals $\varepsilon$ but how do we prove that both are smaller than $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ ? Or why that should be the case in the first place. Sorry if I come across as being a bit slow.

Comment: Sorry I understand that now... and since $\frac{\varepsilon}{2} > 0$ we can add both sides of operator together and that is the proof?

Comment: further hint: To complete the proof, you must choose $N = \max{N_1,N_2}$. and use the triangle inequality to bound $|x_n + y_n - L - M | $

Comment: Gotcha, cheers !